# How to make Section of rounded images android?

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout, android-studio

I'm working on a project that have events and the user view the event and choose to attend it or not, the question is.. I need to make a section of rounded images which is appear in the attached picture of the people who attend this event to be viewed by the event viewer!!

How can I do this?

[image: Rounded Images Picture]

Answer (score 1):

you can dynamically add views in your layout.

Here in code you are adding views in LinearLayout layout_list_view
your_activity.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layout_list_view"
                android:gravity="center"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"       
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>
```

This your CircleImageView of users those are attending event.
add_view.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp">
             <com.leafwearables.saferkids.customViews.AppCompatCircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/temp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>
```

create a ViewHolder for your view

```
            public class UserVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

             public UserVH(View inflate, int ind) {
                    super(inflate);
                    index = ind;
                    baseView = itemView;
                    initialize(itemView);
                }

                 private void initialize(View itemView) {
                    imageView = (AppCompatCircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                }


                public int getIndex() {
                    return index;
                }

                public View getBaseView() {
                    return baseView;
                }

            }
```

YourActivty.class

```
         private void addUsersView() {

                        LinearLayout user_list_view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_list_view);
                        final UserVH[] views = new UserVH[userList.size()];
                         for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
                         views[i] = new UserVH(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.add_view, null), i);
                                   try {
                                        File profileFile = new File(getProfileDir(this), child.getDeviceId());
                                        if (profileFile.exists()) {
                                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(profileFile.getPath());
                                            views[i].imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    user_list_view.addView(views[i].getBaseView(), -1, 60);

                                    }

                        } 

                          public  File getProfileDir(Context context) {
                                File fileProfile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "USERS");
                                fileProfile.mkdir();
                                return fileProfile;
                            }
```

Hope this will help :)